# Setting ReactNative's NativeModules.RNDeviceInfo with Jest

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I'm attempting to switch my react native application over from using Mocha/Chai to Jest but I'm running into an issue.

Previously in my `test/setup.js` I had something along the lines of:

```js
const NativeModules = require('react-native-mock-render').NativeModules;
const MockRNDeviceInfo = require('./support/mock-device-info.js').MockRNDeviceInfo;
NativeModules.RNDeviceInfo = MockRNDeviceInfo;
```

This however doesn't work with jest as I get the following error when attempting to test one of my components:

```js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'appVersion' of undefined
  at Object.getVersion (node_modules/react-native-device-info/deviceinfo.js:39:20)
```

What is the proper way to set values on `NativeModules`?

Comment: Is there any additional code that might help reproduce this error? What is in `./support/mock-device-info.js`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Jest you can mock modules using something like:

```js
jest.mock('react-native-device-info', () => {
  return {
    getVersion: () => 4
  }
})
```

I've only mocked the `getVersion` method and returned a random number, since that's the one that is failing for you, but you might have to add the ones you're using in your application (and change the value to the one you want).

You can also use the [jest.fn](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/mock-functions.html) util to mock the functions of the module.

Comment: I really think the `setupFile` route will be better in the long term, rather than mocking in each test. See my answer.

Comment: The OP already has a setup file, I don't know what you already talking about.

Comment: Good answer for 2017, but now `react-native-device-info` provides its own mock to use. See below answer from @Hasseeb

Answer (score 19):

#### 2020 answer

These days, `react-native-device-info` provides a test helper.

So, it can be done using

```js
import mockRNDeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info/jest/react-native-device-info-mock'; // or use require

jest.mock('react-native-device-info', () => mockRNDeviceInfo);
```

Link to the file https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info/blob/cd60ebeeab28611dd122dff0a5ae1fdd40733a80/jest/react-native-device-info-mock.js

Comment: Also available in [the troubleshooting](https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info#troubleshooting) of the documentation

Answer (score 0):

You could also create file inside the `__mocks__` folder called `react-native-device-info.js`

And inside the file put the following

```
import mockRNDeviceInfo from "react-native-device-info/jest/react-native-device-info-mock";

export default mockRNDeviceInfo;
```

This is also specified in the [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks)

Answer (score -3):

I do not have much experience with react myself but I do have a friend that does. I mentioned this to him, and  he said you should restart the packager. You can do that by first:

terminate the packager by exiting the terminal window

then

manually start with:

```
$ react-native start
```

I hope this helps somehow!